# React router does not match a route when redirected from elsewhere

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a `Route` setup like this:

```
<Route path="/(login|signup|reset|activate)" component={AuthPages} />
```

Elsewhere in my code I have a `Redirect` setup like this:

```
const urlSearch = window.location.search;
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login" + urlSearch,
    state: {
      from: props.location,
      showWarning: true
    }
  }}
/>
```

But when this redirect happens, for some reason the route does not match. If I refresh the page, then the route matches fine and the `AuthPages` component is appropriately rendered.

I'm not sure what's going on here. Could somebody help?

Comment: Would the strict prop help you? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/strict-bool

Comment: @PedroOtero I don’t see how it could but I could give a try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is to provide the query string to the `search` property inside the `location` object to the `Redirect` component like this:

```
<Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        search: urlSearch,
        state: {
          from: props.location,
          showWarning: true
        }
      }}
 />
```

This works perfectly.